# Eliminate unnecessary XSL test on a string variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to find elements that the postal code in the US is between a certain range of numbers(130-160).

Is there an easier way to code this logic on a string value for a postal code instead of doing 32 "starts-with(PostalCode, '103')" or.........:

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'130')or starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'131')or starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'132')or starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'133')or starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'134')or starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'135')or starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'136')or starts-with(//Order/Address/PostalCode,'137')">
```

There already is > than 300 xsl:choose :when's and :otherwise lines in this monstrosity and I wrote it without a single line of comments. This way just seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are only going to be looking at the first three digits, you could first set a variable to hold these first three digits

```
<xsl:variable name="zip" select="number(substring(//Order/Address/PostalCode, 1, 3))" />
```

Then it becomes straight-forward to check the range

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$zip >= 130 and $zip &lt;= 160">Hurrah!</xsl:when>
```

To be a bit more flexible, you could parameterise this...

```
<xsl:param name="first" select="130" />
<xsl:param name="last" select="160" />
```

Then you would use the parameters, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="zip" select="number(substring(//Order/Address/PostalCode, 1, string-length($first)))" />
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$zip >= $first and $zip &lt;= $last">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test for:

```
<xsl:variable name="subcode" select="substring(PostalCode, 1, 3)" />
<xsl:if test="130 &lt;= $subcode and $subcode &lt;= 160">
    <!-- result if true -->
</xsl:if>
```

However, if you want to find elements that meet this condition, you should use this in a *predicate*.

Comment: Lets say for instance a Canadian post code was used instead, they contain letters will it just be ignored because it cannot convert a string to a number

Comment: @zerodoc We can only answer the questions that you ask. If you have a different question, then either edit this one or post a new one.